# Does clearing timeout/interval have to be inside `useEffect` react hook?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm wondering what is the correct way and best practice to clear timeouts/intervals when using React hooks. For example I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  const id = useRef(null)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5)
  const [timesClicked, setTimesClicked] = useState(0)

  if (!count) {
    clearInterval(id.current)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    id.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count -1)
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id.current)
    }
  }, [])

  const onClick = () => setTimesClicked(timesClicked => timesClicked + 1)

  return (
    <div>countdown: {count >= 0 ? count : 0}
      <hr />
      Clicked so far: {timesClicked}
      {count >= 0 && <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When `count` equals 0 the interval is cleared in the body of the `Test` function. In most of the examples I've seen on the Internet interval is cleared inside `useEffect`, is this mandatory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be sure to clear all intervals before your component gets unmounted.
Intervals never disappear automatically when components get unmounted and to clear them, `clearInterval` is often called inside useEffect(() => {}, []).

The function retured in useEffect(() => {}, []) gets called when the compoment is unmounted.

```
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id.current)
    }
```

You can see that intervals set inside a component never disappears automatically by checking this sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-oij8s

Intervals remain forever unless `clearInterval` is called.

Comment: My question is whether clearing interval has to occur inside `useEffect`. In my example, I'm clearing the interval not inside `useEffect` but in the body of the functional component. Are their any disadvantages to my method?

Comment: Components get updated frequently for many reasons and everytime it happens, your `if (!count)` will be called. So it would be better to use `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is a `function` which is executed repeatedly and it returns an `id` of the interval. When you call `clearInterval` with this id, you stop that `function` from repeating. It's not mandatory to do it inside a certain `function`, you need to clear it when you no longer want that `function` to be called subsequently. You can call it in the `function` you return as a result of `useEffect`, if that's what you need.